# jsDoc typedef property reference

Tags: jsdoc

I am using `@typedef` to define some custom types, with `@property` items.

When doing the same for a class I can just use `{@link MyClass#property}` to reference the property.

But for some reasons `{@link MyType#property}` does not resolve.

Is this a bug or is there a different way to reference such properties?

My usage example:

```
/**
 * @typedef helpers.Column
 *
 * @property {String} name
 */

/**
 * This one resolves correctly: {@link helpers.Column}
 *
 * This one does not resolve: {@link helpers.Column#name}
 */
```